# Pagination logic for system with 2 API layers

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, pagination

I have a system with 2 levels of API. API A the one which exposes the DB and API B which calls API A processes and transforms its data and finally gives a response to the final consumer.

In a particular transformation API B needs to multiply an item collection retrieved by API A by 4 (And add some fields etc.) API A has a classic pagination implementation (PageSize and PageNumber in the query). How can I implement pagination on API B? (I just need the logic no code)

I have found two solutions but I don't like them:

1. Allowing only page sizes that are multiple of 4. When the consumer
   calls API B I divide the page number by 4 and then call API A, I multiply the retrieved items by 4 and return to the consumer.
2. Passing directly pagination data in API A, multiply the collection by
   4 and return it to the consumer with API A pagination metadata(Total
   count, page number, size, next page, prev page). But this way if the
   consumer asks for 100 items he gets 400.

Thanks